# Are "history" questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-questions, scope

We have a couple of questions asking where something comes from and is essentially history-related.

---

The ones here probably aren't as useful for modern language use.

[Japanese/Chinese numbers usage timeline](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19/)

[Origin of the circle in ぬ, ね, and る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23/)

[Why were ゐ and ゑ eliminated?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/88/)

These are seen on a regular basis on the Internet so they serve a purpose.

[Where does なう on Twitter come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/140/)

[Use of 厨 on the Internet](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/239/)

---

Do we draw a line anywhere for history questions or are we not really concerned as long as they asking for the origin of some Japanese word or phrase?

Answer (score 16):

I think they are appropriate.

Studying the history, the development of a language and the etymology of its words can be very useful sometimes to understand the language now.

Meanings can change, words can change, but learning the history and the origin can help you to have a wider view on the language, that's my opinion.