# Are questions on Okinawan or other Ryukyuan languages on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

The [Ryukyuan languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryukyuan_languages), the indigenous languages of southern Japan, are related to the Japanese language. Should questions on them be on-topic on JL&U?

If they are, I will be asking a few questions on Okinawan.

Comment: It is up to you, but it might be better to ask one question first and see how it goes instead of asking a few at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting proposal to make them on-topic, but are there enough people here who have knowledge of Okinawan or other Ryukyuan languages? I guess the biggest problem that I could see is questions being asked and nobody being able to answer them. Still, I don't think it'd hurt to ask one or two and find out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes

- Since Ryukyuan languages are genetically related to Japanese, questions about Ryukyuan languages can expose or touch upon interesting aspects of historical Japanese. For example, Okinawan's use of *nu* as a non-honorific nominative particle is related to the nominative use of の in Classical Japanese. [Historical Japanese is explicitly on-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-history-questions-appropriate), so allowing Ryukyuan languages is a straightforward extension.
- Ryukyuan languages act as a substratum for the dialects of Japanese spoken in the Ryukyus (e.g. [Okinawan Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_Japanese)). Hence Ryukyuan languages are directly relevant for discussing Japanese dialects, which are also explicitly on-topic.
- Considering the small number of speakers, these languages will never get their own Language and Usage sites. If questions on them go anywhere, it would be here.
- For the same reason, questions on Ryukyuan languages are unlikely to swamp pure-Japanese questions or detract from the JL&U site.
- JL&U has many users in Japan, who are more likely to be familiar with or interested in Ryukyuan languages than users on a general Languages site.