# Shouldn't the tag `okinawan` rather be `ryukyuan`?

Tags: discussion, tags

It has been decided that [Ryukyuan languages are on topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/944/are-questions-on-okinawan-or-other-ryukyuan-languages-on-topic). However, there are at least five Ryukyuan languages, but the tag is called `okinawan`, after one of those. Shouldn't it rather be `ryukyuan`, with `okinawan` relegated to a synonym, together with `amami` and the other possible names. I believe it misdefines the scope of the tagging; furthermore, out of the already existing questions not all are specifically on Okinawan; [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/do-japaneses-sister-languages-have-equivalents-of-the-particles-%E3%81%AF-and-%E3%82%92), say, is not. So renaming the tag would be a possibility to define the questions more exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with renaming the tag.

We usually go for shorter tags, but maybe in this case [ryukyuan-languages](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ryukyuan-languages) might be less confusing for someone typing `okinawan`...?

We usually transcribe Japanese in modified Hepburn ([rōmaji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r%c5%8dmaji) [renyōkei](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reny%c5%8dkei) [manyōgana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/many%c5%8dgana)) but I'm not sure if [ryūkyūan-languages](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ry%c5%abky%c5%aban-languages) makes sense here — it's a Japanese place name with an English suffix *-an*.

I hope others will chime in so we can come to an agreement about the naming.

***Edit***. The tag [ryukyuan-languages](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ryukyuan-languages) is now live with [okinawan](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okinawan) as synonym and the following tag excerpt:

> 琉球語派. Indigenous languages of the Ryūkyū Islands, including Okinawan (ウチナーグチ, 沖縄語), Miyako (ミャークフツ・スマフツ, 宮古口・島口), Yaeyama (ヤイマムニ, 八重山物言) and others. These languages are distinct from Japanese and are not to be confused with local dialects of Japanese such as Okinawan Japanese (ウチナーヤマトグチ, 沖縄大和口, 沖縄弁) which is Japanese as spoken by the people of Okinawa Prefecture.

Comments and suggestions are still welcome!

Comment: I agree, the best name would be `ryukyuan-languages`.